# Rendering hair particles appears grainy

Tags: rendering, particles

[image][image][image]I tried following Andrew Price's tutorial on realistic grass, by adding the default hair particle system to the plane and setting the render to a group of grass, but the grass appears grainy today. Although yesterday I got a realistic one. I don't know what went wrong?

Comment: screenshots and .blend file will help to diagnostic the problem

Comment: hard to say what's the difference between your yesterday and today renders...

Comment: check if you assigned your grass group to your hairs, also check size. your hair system doesn't look like going up, check emission settings and velocity, and/or children roughness settings.

Comment: Looks like you moved the group you were instancing.